# How to pass a variable from javascript (coffeescript) to rails controller?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I guess this should be simple, but I can't figure it out

I my view there is a link that I want to trigger some ajax:

```
link_to( "#{sir.sir_id}" , '#', :data => {'sir-id' => sir.id}, remote: true ),
```

In my coffeescript I can get the value of the data-attribute in the link like so:

```
$ ->
  $("a[data-sir-id]").click ->
  data_sir_id = $(this).data("sir-id")
```

So I need the value of that variable (data_sir_id) in my controller, so I can get its associated model objects and render them in the same view

How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to store your data in a data attribute and to make an ajax call when clicking on the link: `link_to` provides you a great way to make link and to pass parameters.

And by using, `remote: true`, it will do an ajax call without any other configuration.

```
link_to("#{sir.sir_id}", path_to_the_controller_action(sir_id: sir.id), remote: true)
```

Then, in your controller action, your data will be accessible in `params[:sir_id]`

Answer (score 1):

Here in `link_to` you have passed url as `'#'`, so if you have a particular action that you can add then you can go [by above way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19616578/2923156)

else you can use the following:

To specify link in view, you can use it as

```
link_to "#{sir.sir_id}", '#', remote: true, 'sir-id' => sir.id, class: 'sir_id_link'
```

In coffeescript:

```
$ ->
  $("sir_id_link").live "click", ->
  data_sir_id = $(@).attr("sir-id")
  $.ajax
    url: any_url
    type: "PUT"
    data:
      sir_id: data_sir_id
    success: (data) ->
      ...
```

Now in your controller action, you can access it as params[:sir_id].

Hope this would help you.

Thanks.